# creating lagged variables according to exposure of each observation

Tags: stata

I have grouped cross-section data and I want to generate some variables that reflect the level of exposure of each observation according to a certain date.
I have individuals who were born at different times and lived in different cities. I also have another database that represents the level of exposure to my variable (conflict) across time for each city.

[image]

So, what I want to do is create a variable that indicates the exposure of each individual to conflict the year before birth and the year after (taking into account that individuals were only interviewed once).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this the long way. I generated different lagged variables for each individual and later generated a variable corresponding to conflict on the year before birth based on several conditions. For example:

```
    gen conflict_birth= conflict-1 if year==yearofbirth+1
```

and so on for the rest of individuals.